# Can't get Facebook Page Access Token after it was removed from apps previously

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm able to get User Access Token ($access_token) successfully but in using **https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$access_token**, it's doing strange things; I can't retrieve the **Page Access Token**. I can get the list of pages the user administrates on most facebook accounts my app is linked to but on a couple of facebook accounts, it's just nothing. In that facebook account's app settings, I cannot see the **"Manage Page" and "Publish Page" permissions** though it's showing fine on other accounts connected to the *same app*. What's going on? Are there settings I might have missed perhaps on those accounts?

**EDIT:**
I just found out this happened after the user removed the app from facebook. Another user who  returned the list of pages fine tried to remove the app as a test and after re-linking it to the app, it stopped returning the list of pages. Does facebook do something else when you remove an app? Where can I reset it?

SOLVED:
getReRequestUrl(array('publish_actions', 'manage_pages', 'publish_pages'))

Comment: Well then most likely that user did not grant those permissions to your app.

Comment: @CBroe If that's the case, shouldn't the user see the options for changing the permissions? How can the user grant my app permission if the options are not there? P.S. Other FB users can see the other permissions

Comment: Users can decline most permissions your app asks for. And if they declined them once, they won't be asked again next time they log in; you either have to specifically re-ask for those permissions (extra parameter on login dialog call), or they have to remove the app from their settings and login "fresh" again afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe The user already removed my app on his facebook apps list and when he re-allowed my app, it still didn't return his facebook pages to me even though there's no permission declined. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Does the user have a role in the app? Did you get the permissions reviewed already?

Comment: @CBroe He's the admin of  the page. What do you mean by review? By facebook? If so, yes. Other facebook users using the same app return list of pages fine except for a couple of them. Is there some settings on their facebook itself maybe that could have caused this?

Comment: Not that I know of. Are those proper, normal user profiles? Not in "using Facebook as a page" mode, not Business Manager users, ...?

Comment: @CBroe I just found out this happened after the user removed the app from facebook. Another user who  returned the list of pages fine tried to remove the app as a test and after re-linking it to the app, it stopped returning the list of pages. Does facebook do something else when you remove an app? Where can I reset it?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a current access token, and not an old one (from database, ...)? Did they really completely remove the app, or just remove certain permissions?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, it's a new access token. I took note of the previous one and now it's different. The user removed the app from facebook, not the permission. Before it was showing list of permissions and now it just shows Post permission after it was REconnected. How can I get it to show the Manage Page and Publish Page permission again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD SCOPES:
getReRequestUrl(array('publish_actions', 'manage_pages', 'publish_pages'))